# How to tell if a laptop is utilizing LPDDR5 Link-ECC functionality?

Tags: laptop, ddr, ecc

JEDEC introduces two kinds of ECC to LPDDR5, that's inline ECC and link ECC. <sup>[[1](https://www.synopsys.com/designware-ip/technical-bulletin/key-features-about-lpddr5.html)]</sup> However, link ECC, which is used to protect data through transmitting, is optional.<sup>[[2](https://picture.iczhiku.com/resource/eetop/SyILhHYzAjOHfcnm.pdf)]</sup>. My question is, how could we tell if a laptop is utilizing link ECC funtion.

Reference:

<sub>[1]: https://www.synopsys.com/designware-ip/technical-bulletin/key-features-about-lpddr5.html</sub>

<sub>[2]: https://picture.iczhiku.com/resource/eetop/SyILhHYzAjOHfcnm.pdf</sub>